How to prevent the Dock from saving images as a web link?
Whenever I save images to my downloads folder (right side of the dock), I tend to drag it from the browser tab into the downloads shortcut on my Dock. However, there's a brief moment where a space is opened up and the image can be saved as a web link. Then, the image won't be saved to my desktop, but the link to that image will be saved as a separate entry in the Dock. This behavior is particularly annoying since it's easy to make the Dock move if you hover and make it arbitrarily move. I would like a solution that prevents links from being able to be saved on the right-hand side of the Dock.
The behavior on video: https://i.imgur.com/v9T8vx1.mp4
I have seen the following approach:
defaults write com.apple.dock contents-immutable -bool true; killall Dock

This accomplishes what I want: Prevent images dragged from a browser from being saved as a dock shortcut. Makes it easy to save images without worrying about the Dock from moving or making space for a shortcut. But this also prevents me from changing or removing apps from the left side of my Dock.
I think this is browser independent, but if it is not, I am using Chromium as my browser. However, I am not going to use the right clicking an image and hitting "Save Image As..." approach. This would be even slower as I'd be given a prompt to save the image, and if the location is wrong, I'll have to navigate to my downloads folder.
